# HtmlUnit: anchor.click is not changing page

Tags: javascript, parsing, htmlunit

I'm trying to parse this page.

http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/czech-republic/extraliga/plzen-liberec-QaikxB6H/#over-under;2

I would like to get info in the table one can get by clicking on one of the line over/under or compare odds. My aim is to get table from over/under +5.5.

I succeded in getting HtmlAnchor and OnClickAttribute, but then new page is not loaded and of course link of the page is the same as the original one.

Here is a part of the code i'm using.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);


....

List<HtmlElement> links = div.getElementsByAttribute("a", "class", "more");

for (int k = 0; k<links.size(); k++) {
    if (links.get(k).getOnClickAttribute().toString().contains("P-5.50")) {
        links.get(k).click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
        System.out.println(page1X2.getUrl().toString());

        file = new File("./test3.csv");
        fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(page1X2.asText());
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Done");

        break;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to find a solution or figure out a different approach?

---

EDIT:

Thank for reply. I tried your code but I'm getting error in for condition (Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type capture#1-of ? to HtmlElement).

Anyway I tried to use the code you posted inside if:

```
        List<HtmlElement> links = div.getElementsByAttribute("a", "class", "more");

        for (HtmlElement anchor : links) {
            if (anchor.getOnClickAttribute().contains("P-5.50")) {
                anchor.click();
                HtmlElement parent = (HtmlElement) anchor.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode();
                HtmlTable table = parent.getFirstByXPath(".//table");
                System.out.println(page1X2.getUrl().toString());
                System.out.println(table.asText());

            }
        }
```

But url is stil the same url and a then null pointer exception when printing table.asText().

---

My goal is to get odds from website. I'd like to cycle on all matches. My expectation is to get odds for 1X2 and U/O 5,5 for alla matches. The error i get is that this part of code

```
        System.out.println(page1X2.<HtmlElement>getByXPath("//a[@class='more']").size());
```

return 0 and so i cannot get table.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCredentialsProvider;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptResult;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNodeList;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableBody;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableDataCell;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableFooter;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.URL;

public class prova {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws MalformedURLException 
 * @throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException 
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00"); // decimali con virgola
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ITALY));

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    String serie = "extraliga"; 
    String pagina = "1";
    String nation = "czech-republic";
    String s = "http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/"+nation+"/"+serie+"/results/#/page/"+pagina+"/";      


    HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage(s);     
    final HtmlDivision htmldiv = myPage.getHtmlElementById("tournamentTable");
    final HtmlTable htmltable = (HtmlTable) htmldiv.getElementsByTagName("table").get(0);
    List<HtmlTableDataCell> matches = htmltable.getElementsByAttribute("td", "class", "name table-participant");

    for (int i=0; i < matches.size(); i++) {

        String link =  "http://www.oddsportal.com"+matches.get(i).getElementsByTagName("a").get(0).getAttribute("href");
        HtmlPage page1X2 = webClient.getPage(link);

        // Quote 1X2
        DomNodeList<HtmlElement> quote1X2 = getQuote1X2(page1X2);
        System.out.println(quote1X2.get(1).asText() + "-" + quote1X2.get(2).asText() + "-" + quote1X2.get(3).asText());

        // get click
        HtmlElement tabUO = page1X2.getHtmlElementById("tab-nav-main").getElementsByAttribute("a", "title", "Over/Under").get(0);
        tabUO.click();

        System.out.println(page1X2.<HtmlElement>getByXPath("//a[@class='more']").size());
        for (HtmlElement anchor : page1X2.<HtmlElement>getByXPath("//a[@class='more']")) {
            if (anchor.getOnClickAttribute().contains("P-5.50")) {
                anchor.click();
                HtmlElement parent = (HtmlElement) anchor.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode();
                HtmlTable table = parent.getFirstByXPath(".//table");
                System.out.println(table.asText());
            }
        }

    }

    webClient.close();
}

// FUNCTION

private static DomNodeList<HtmlElement> getQuote1X2(HtmlPage matchPage) {

        HtmlTableBody matchTable = (HtmlTableBody) matchPage.getElementsByTagName("tbody").get(0);
        List<HtmlElement> row = matchTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        int j;
        for (j = 0; j<row.size()-1; j++) {
            if (row.get(j).getElementsByTagName("td").get(0).asText().trim().compareTo("bet365.it")==0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        DomNodeList<HtmlElement> quote = null;
        if (j<row.size()-1)
            quote = row.get(j).getElementsByTagName("td");
        else
        {
            HtmlTableFooter matchFootTable = (HtmlTableFooter) matchPage.getElementsByTagName("tfoot").get(0);
            List<HtmlElement> averrow = matchFootTable.getElementsByAttribute("tr", "class", "aver");
            quote = averrow.get(0).getElementsByTagName("td");
        }

    return quote;

}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) case, explaining what the error is, and what the expectations are

Comment: I update with full case. Now (and i dont know why) i noted that even tabUO.click(); is not loading new page. I was sure it was loading.

Comment: Finally i solved. Problem was that i need to call tabUO.onmouseDown() since attribute is onmousedown. I think i previous version of htmlunit there was not this method or i couldn't find it. Anyway may thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

When you click on real browser, the page is the same, but the URL changes.

The same thing is done with `HtmlUnit`:

```
try (WebClient webclient = new WebClient()) {
    HtmlPage page = webclient.getPage("http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/czech-republic/extraliga/plzen-liberec-QaikxB6H/#over-under;2");
    for (HtmlElement anchor : page.<HtmlElement>getByXPath("//a[@class='more']")) {
        if (anchor.getOnClickAttribute().contains("P-5.50")) {
            anchor.click();
            HtmlElement parent = (HtmlElement) anchor.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode();
            HtmlTable table = parent.getFirstByXPath(".//table");
            System.out.println(table.asText());
            System.out.println(table.asXml());
        }
    }
}
```

In XPath, `.` means from this node, `/` means direct child, and `//` means children or grandchildren recursively, and `@class='more'` means find attribute `class` with value `more`.

Comment: Thank you for answering and explanation. I tried your code, but it's not working. Above I added some detalis.

Comment: The code works with [latest snapshot](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts), please give it a try

Comment: I tried with latest version. It's no more giving error, but anyway it's not working. I tried to write a new simpler program just with your code and it works, but when I put it into more complex code i get that size of page.<HtmlElement>getByXPath("//a[@class='more']") is 0.

Have you any idea? Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Please specify more, with your goal and code. The answer was to fulfil the initial question

Comment: I provided more info in the quesion